# [EBean][PlayFramewrok 2.5] ID is not loaded from database

Tags: java, mysql, ebean

I am using:

```
 "org.avaje.ebean" % "ebean" % "9.5.1"
```

and MySql databse

I have this model:

```
@Entity
public class Record extends Model {

    /**
     *  Name of column for ID
     */
    public static final String ID_COL_NAME="ID";
    /**
     * ID of record
     */
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column(name = ID_COL_NAME)
    public long ID;
```

Other attributes which are loaded succesfully

Once ebean created databse, I loaded it with some data. It went correctly and ID were also generated.
However when I use findAll() to get objects with ebean , ID is 0 so not loaded in all of them.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `setDistinct(true)` in my query therefore IDs were not loaded